# Installer crashes when selecting partition, and using trial mode

Tags: crash

after searching the net I decided to post my problem here.

I'm trying to install Elementary OS with a CD , dual boot with windows 10.
Created a 2nd partition, on which I'm trying to install it.
I burnt the ISO via Windows Explorer.
I can start the Installation,
during loading, before the installer menu this signal appears:
https://elementaryforums.com/index.php?attachments/upload_2020-7-10_18-0-14-png.351/
and then disappears. NOTE: an USB stick is not connected.
when it gets to the part of installing on which partition and choosing next,
the installer crashes,

It happens while using the option of installing it next to the windows or on a second partition.
no error signal, the monitor shuts down but the computer itself doesn't but it seems that the processor and DVD drive become very silent and stop.

When I use the trial mode over the DVD the systems crashes after some time, randomly. The computer doesn't completely shut down, like previously it seems only the processor and DVD drive.
I met problems also with UBUNTU, which I tried to install afterwards. But Ubuntu doesn't even let me into the menu, the loading screen appears, then the monitor shuts off, the DVD drive begins to work very loudly for a couple of minutes and then everything shutsdown except the computer itself (the light that it's on). It's pretty frustrating.

I don't have EFI or UEFI on my system. I use IDE , legacy mode supported, did a RAM check with windows and everything is fine. I would be very glad if you can help me.

Comment: Can you use usb stick instead of the CD? Just download and install balena etcher, then open balena etcher, pick up the iso image and usb stick in balena etcher and the software will do the rest. The partition for Elementary OS should be done in Windows - in disk management. Actually just as empty unformatted space. Then disable fast boot in Windows power saving - look for in Google how to do it. After that disable the secure boot in BIOS, save exit press F12 and hold, wait, choose usb stick to boot and choose install Elementary OS.

Comment: Then during the installation just choose this empty space and Elementary OS will use it and create partitions itself.

Comment: The question is why you are using IDE mode instead of AHCI? I recommend to switch to AHCI first, before the installation. https://support.thinkcritical.com/kb/articles/switch-windows-10-from-raid-ide-to-ahci

Comment: Hi sysadmin, thank you for your answer! I use USB because I couldn't get my computer to boot from USB with every method whatsoever. So I already created a 2nd partition in ext4 format. I installed windows using IDE. If I switch it to AHCI Windows doesn't start anymore.

Comment: So should I delete the partition, leave it as unused space and try again?

Comment: I tried the method on the website for switching to AHCI. Changing to secure windows boot, then changing to AHCI in Bios, windows won't boot afterwards, no disk

Comment: Hmm. That is really strange. Can you switch back settings in BIOS to previous state and check does Windows 10 starts? Yes, there should not be a ext4 partition, but just empty space after disk resize in Windows 10.

Comment: So, by deleting the volume and setting it as simply free space and not checking the "install third party" drivers I got to the installation process after selecting the timezone. Then it gets to "copying data" and the monitors shut off and the cd drive goes haywire for a minute and then shutsdown too.
I couldn't get the AHCI change to work, even with regedit and resetting the BIOS. I tried to install elementary OS in AHCI mode with the same result as above. And my intern wifi card has stopped working haha

Comment: somehow the wifi card started working again for no reason than unplugging the cable of the power supply

Comment: Well, that is really strange situation. I have to confess that first time I read something like that. Unfortunately I have no idea why the machine shuts down during the installation process. I remember that many years ago me and my high school friend discovered that we need nero burning rome full version, to be able to choose the speed of the burning cd / dvd. We always burn discs with Windows 98 at the lowest possible speed to avoid errors during burning process. Windows 10 default soft does not allow to choose burn speed. The best option is to choose 1x speed. However not every drive allows.

Comment: You can try burn XP software. It is for free and allows to choose the burning speed. I do not know what the lowest possible speed your drive is able to handle. You must check and give it a try. Of course the CD must be without any single dirt on it's surface.

Comment: Please also provide the computer model and mother board. You can install speccy from Piriform in Windows 10, make a snapshot of hardware settings with this program and, zip it and send to me through an e-mail. I am not sure is Elementary OS able to handle Wi-Fi adapter or motherboard. Anyway worth to check it.

Comment: the motherboard is a msi ms 7502. I updated the bios, deleted the partition in the windows part manager, had it previously managed with EasePart, maybe this broke something. Anyways. So I was able to boot over USB after the BIOS update, elementary OS crashed like it did with the DVD. So I tried Ubuntu,- and could install it! Now the problem is that the system crashes couple minutes after booting up and the graphics card is not running the whole time. But since it's now an Ubuntu problem and I probably have given up on Elementary OS I'll search on. Thank you very much for your time and input.

Comment: You need to install the firmware for the GPU (graphic card) in Ubuntu. You can try this solution. Just try to run Ubuntu, when the login screen will appear or the desktop. Just press ctrl+alt+f1 to f6 and login there and then type sudo update-initramfs -u in the terminal. See the error about missing firmware. If it will be there, then you can install in Ubuntu the driver for the graphic card in the upgrade center or sth like that. Ctrl+Alt+F7 will switch go back to the desktop mode (graphical environment).